# Swift / SwitUI App crashes, when changing device Orientation after defining a position in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, orientation, scroll-position

My App keeps on crashing when I change the device orientation if I did set a `scrollPosition` before.
My `ContentView()` looks smth like this - where I'm reading out the display-size.

```
GeometryReader { display in
    VStack {
        HeaderView()
        MainScrollView(display: display)
        FooterView()
    }
}
```

Passing `display` on to the `MainScrollView()`, where - inside a `ScrollViewReader` an `if-else`-statement checks if it should load the `PortraitMainView()` or the `LandscapeMainView()

```
struct MainScrollView: View {
    var display: GeometryProxy
    var body: some View {
    
        ScrollViewReader { scrollPosition in
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    if display.size.width > display.size.height {
                        LandscapeMainView()
                    } else {
                        PortraitMainView()
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollPosition.scrollTo("C", anchor: .top)
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Scroll to Position C")
                } )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LandscapeMainView() and PortaitMainView() look like this:

```
LandscapeMainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Item A")
                .id("A")
            Text("Item B")
                .id("B")
            Text("Item C")
                .id("C")
            Text("Item D")
                .id("D")
            Text("Item E")
                .id("E")
        }
    }
}
```

It all works fine, I can flip the orientation and it changes from `LandscapeMainView()` to `PortraitMainView()` and vice versa.
Also, setting a `scrollPosition` works like a charm in Landscape and Portrait Mode.
Only after I set a `scrollPosition` and then change the orientation my device freezes, giving me an `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)` as output. The Screen still shows the Portrait mode, tilted on the Landscape, leaving half of the screen blank.
Is there a better way to handle screen orientation and scrollviews in SwiftUI?

Comment: Provided code is not enough to reproduce crash, would you provided minimal example?

Comment: Updated the code - while trying if it crashes I found out that it doesn't crash on the simulator. Tried my actual app on the simulator: works like expected. This code on my iPhone XS with iOS 14 crashes though.

Comment: Try passing bool instead of `GeometryProxy` to your `MainScrollView`. I had similar issue, so it's just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GeometryProxy` causes issues when you try to pass it anywhere (for me as well).
SwiftUI is closed source, so I can't explain what magical pointers issue is happening here. But this code is confirmed to be working as per comments.

```swift
GeometryReader { display in
    VStack {
        HeaderView()
        MainScrollView(display: display.size.width > display.size.height)
        FooterView()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MainScrollView: View {
    var display: Boolean
    var body: some View {
    
        ScrollViewReader { scrollPosition in
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    if display {
                        LandscapeMainView()
                    } else {
                        PortraitMainView()
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollPosition.scrollTo("C", anchor: .top)
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Scroll to Position C")
                } )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus: same crashes happen with `ScrollViewProxy`, be careful with those.

My uneducated guess, why this happening: `GeometryProxy` is holding reference to parent widget, which is deallocated while being rebuilt, but child widget isn't rebuilt because argument didn't changed so it hits deallocated pointer.